# how to make a navigation 100% width within an header wrapper

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with 100% width, that distributes equally within a header that also has a width of 100%. Also each `a` element has two words each, that are perfectlly center aligned under each other.

The HTML I'm working with is below:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span style="font-family:sacramento; text-align: center;">Our</span><br> HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span style="font-family:sacramento;text-align: center;">About</span><br> US</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><span style="font-family:sacramento;text-align: center;">Client</span><br> WORKS</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><span style="font-family:sacramento;text-align: center;">Contact</span><br> US</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><span style="font-family:sacramento;text-align: center;">Our</span><br> VISION</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><span style="font-family:sacramento;text-align: center;">Our</span><br> BIOS</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div><!--end of nav-->
```

CSS I'm working with

```
.nav {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
 }
 .nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
 .nav li {
margin: 25px 80px 10px 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
 }
 .nav a {
padding: 3px 12px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #999;
line-height: 100%;
font-family: actor;
font-size: 20px;
width: 10px;

   }
```

The example I'm trying to make looks like this below :

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I try the code in IE9, I get this image :

[image]

Please how can i solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To distribute all items equally set a percentage width on the list items. You have six items so add `width: 16%;` to the `.nav li` rule.

To center align the text change:

```
 .nav a {
padding: 3px 12px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #999;
line-height: 100%;
font-family: actor;
font-size: 15px;
width: 10px;

   }
```

to (removed explicit width and added display: block):

```
 .nav a {
padding: 3px 12px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #999;
line-height: 100%;
font-family: actor;
font-size: 15px;
display: block;
   }
```

Lastly remove `display: inline-block` from the `.nav li` rule and add `float: left`. You should also add a `<div style="clear: both"></div>` element below the list (the  tag) to "fix" the page flow.

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. But I have a little more problem. Please see update.

Comment: I added one more paragraph at the bottom of my answer which handles that issue.

Comment: Thank you kjetilh, when I added float: right, the even distribution does not work..thereby spaces are left to the left and when I did float:left, spaces are lest to the right. I added width: 13%; so as to distribute the li

Comment: That's right. It's nearly impossible to get it absolutely right when using percentages along with fixed width properties such as margins and paddings. It's possible to use percentage values with decimals such as 16.5% but it's has questionable browser support. For best accuracy you can use fixed widths.

Answer (score 0):

Check this JSfiddle : [JSfiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/VvgS2/)

See the result here [Result of navigation](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/VvgS2/show/)

Use this css

```
  .nav {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
      }
  .nav ul {
  margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
       }
     .nav li {
     margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
      }
      .nav a {
       padding: 3px 2px;
       text-decoration: none;
       color: #999;
       line-height: 100%;
     font-family: actor;
       font-size: 15px;
       width: 10px;



        }
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. But I have a little more problem. Please see update.